# SwiftUI no hide animation

Tags: swiftui

I have noticed that when I'm coloring the background I will not get animations when removing Views.

[image]

If I remove `Color(.orange).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` then hide animation will work, otherwise `Modal` will disappear abruptly. Any solutions?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    
    func toggle() {
        withAnimation {
            show = true
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color(.orange).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button(action: toggle) {
                Text("Modal")
            }
            
            if show {
                Modal(show: $show)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Modal: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    
    func toggle() {
        withAnimation {
            show = false
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemGray4).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button(action: toggle) {
                Text("Close")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make animatable container holding removed view (and this makes possible to keep animation in one place). Here is possible solution.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false

    func toggle() {
        show = true      // animation not requried
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            Color(.orange).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Button(action: toggle) {
                Text("Modal")
            }

                VStack {                      // << major changes
                    if show {
                         Modal(show: $show)
                    }
                }.animation(.default)        // << !!
        }
    }
}

struct Modal: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool

    func toggle() {
        show = false      // animation not requried
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemGray4).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Button(action: toggle) {
                Text("Close")
            }
        }
    }
}
```